# How to put indicators on the JQuery's JSlider?

Tags: jquery, jslider

I have a Jquery slider.

```
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<STYLE>
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 1px !important; }
    </STYLE>

<SCRIPT>
    $(function() {
        $( "#glider" ).slider({step:10, animate:true, min:0, max:100, value:50});


    });
    </SCRIPT>   

<DIV class=demo>
<DIV id=glider></DIV></DIV>
```

[image: This is the output of above JQuery slider code]

How can I put notches on the steps for 10 values I want to put some notch on each step like on 0, 10, 20, 30 ....100.   How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @veer7 to clarify when you say notches, it's not the steps per-say like in Satya's answer - but "visual notches"?

Comment: @Alex: values just places slider's movable nothes.  However I want soem way to put marker like 0,10,20  like that

Comment: Thanks @veer7 so a sort of visual marker where the steps are drawn out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the handle is styleed using a % left of the

```
<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 10%;"></a>
```

Of it's containing slider:

```
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 10%;"></a></div>
```

So I'm guessing perhaps if you can extract the slider points to work out the % and then style your marker notches using the same %'s.

I'm afraid mine isn't the whole answer, as I'm unsure without digging into it how to get the slider points out as a percentage. Perhaps take a look at the unminified version of jquery-ui slider and see how the percentage is calculated?

Comment: Hi @veer7 if you managed to find a solution, would be really cool if you could post it on jsfiddle it would be cool to see what you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

use `values: [0, 10,20 ]` that should work

Comment: that just puts movable notches I want soemthing like markers which will be in place always.

Comment: check the css properties for the slider , they are going to help

Comment: true Satya. However to be frank I have very little knowledge of css can I get some reference of css for slider.